# Problem with centering Images in a column (beamer)

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have a strange problem centering an image in a column.

I m going to create a presentation with `Beamer` and I created a slide with 2 columns.

The idea (conceptually) is to display the first image, then the second and then comes the last one which should replace the first 2 BUT be vertically centered
I don t know how, but my last image goes at the bottom of the slide.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\graphicspath{{bilder_pre/}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TEXT - \textsl{TEXT TEXT TEXT}}

 \begin{block}{Auswirkung der dcckbcskjcbsc}
      Kommentar
 \end{block}

 \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}

                \visible<1-2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{foto1}}
                \visible<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{foto2}}%
                \llap{\includegraphics<3->[scale=0.2]{foto3}}

      \end{column}

      \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
%                   \includegraphics<1->[scale=0.2]{Abbildung4_2}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
 %                   \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.2]{Abbildung4_1}
      \end{column}
 \end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I tried every combination: `\centering{}`, `\parbox`, `\begin{overlayarea}` and `\begin{overprint}`. No matter...

What could I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @PeterJansson Make sure you are not overwriting an already posted edit during your edits.

Comment: can't test it but you probably want a `\leavevmode` before that `\llap`

Comment: I think you need a formal welcome so [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are a solution with `\parbox` and `\only`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TEXT - \textsl{TEXT TEXT TEXT}}
\begin{block}{Auswirkung der dcckbcskjcbsc}
Kommentar
\end{block}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}

%better than scale: width + height + keepaspectratio

\parbox[c][.6\textheight][c]{\columnwidth}{%
\only<1-2>{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,%
    height=.3\textheight,keepaspectratio]{foto1}\\%
\visible<2>{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,%
    height=.3\textheight,keepaspectratio]{foto2}}%
}
\only<3>{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,%
    height=.3\textheight,keepaspectratio]{foto3}%
}}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]