# Tabular vertical aligning one column next to a column with images

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

None of my efforts to vertically center the second column are working.

First trying the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=3.0in,paperwidth=4.0in,margin=0.65in,
             heightrounded,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx, array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\myBioLoss{Biodiversity_Loss_CutTree.png} 
\def\myPollution{Pollute_Smokestack.png}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l m{2cm}}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Ecological Ceiling}  \\
        \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{\myBioLoss} & Biodiversity    \\
        \includegraphics[width=.10\textwidth]{\myPollution} & Pollution     \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But I get [image: [![Not vertically centered][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6tUE.png]

I've tried `adjustbox` from: [Centering a column vertically with longtable and pictures in rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571729/centering-a-column-vertically-with-longtable-and-pictures-in-rows)
which compiled but did not center.

I've tried `tabularx` and `\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}` from [Vertically center text in tabularx table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104544/vertically-center-text-in-tabularx-table), which compiled with the environment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l m{2cm}}` but did not center.

I've tried `tabular*` from [Right-centered columns in tabular*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478707/right-centered-columns-in-tabular), but this also compiled but did not center.

Lastly, this is for beamer: [Problem with centering Images in a column (beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91394/problem-with-centering-images-in-a-column-beamer) which does not help me.

Yes, I need the `book` class.

Comment: you have l in the first column and m in the second so as shown in your image you have aligned the vertical centre of the second column with the baseline of the first.

Comment: Try `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{…}}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks! The alignment was fixed once I used `>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm}` for both columns.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use  of the `adjusbox` packages which enable moving images baselines position, adding margins etc. For inserting image it offer `\adjustimage` which can replace `includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=3.0in,paperwidth=4.0in,margin=0.65in,
            heightrounded,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, multirow, tabularx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}          % it also load graphicx package
\def\myBioLoss{Biodiversity_Loss_CutTree.png}
\def\myPollution{Pollute_Smokestack.png}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \adjustboxset{width=.1\textwidth,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l m{2cm}}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Ecological Ceiling}  \\
        \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}%{\myBioLoss} 
            & Biodiversity    \\
        \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}%{\myPollution} 
            & Pollution     \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @leandriis, you right. I comment this code line :-(. Corrected now!